# Partitions in Peano-Jordan measure

Tags: measure-theory

If I have a plurinterval $ P $ and its finite partition $\lbrace I_1, I_2,\cdots , I_n \rbrace$, I define the measure of $ P $ as $m (P)=\sum_{i=1}^n m (I_i)$. How I can prove that the measure do not dipent from the particoular partition?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. First show that by induction on $m$ for any partition $I = \biguplus_{j=1}^m J_j$ of an *interval* into *intervals*, we have 
$$ m(I) = \sum_{j=1}^m m(J_j) $$
then use the above as follows: If $P = \biguplus_{i=1}^n I_i = \biguplus_{k=1}^\ell J_k$ are two partitions of $P$, then look at $\{I_i \cap J_k: i,k\}$. Its a partition of $P$ into intervals, and we have 
$$ m(I_i) = \sum_{k=1}^\ell m(I_i \cap J_k) $$
and $$ m(J_k) = \sum_{i=1}^n m(I_i \cap J_k) $$
from the first part. Now conclude.